# How to make iterative loop for Pandas column name extraction more efficient?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

How do I make this code more efficient? I am trying to implement the below-given logic on a much bigger data frame of 100 columns. The idea is to take the required keywords and perform further filtering like 
filtered_df = df[result]

```py
search_list= ['A','B']
df_column_names=['Apple','Airplanne','Banana','Ball','Bat','Cat','Champ','Dog','OX','Zebra']
result=[]

for search_string in search_list:
    for column_name in df_column_names:
        if search_string in column_name:
            result.append(column_name)
```

result =['Apple', 'Airplanne', 'Banana', 'Ball', 'Bat']

Get the result and perform filtering like
filtered_df = df[result]

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html

Comment: this is what you looking for? `[y for x in search_list for y in df_column_names if x in y]`

Comment: Check str.contains

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a regular expression directly to a `pandas.DataFrame.filter`.  In this case, it's quite a basic RegEx.

---

```
df.filter(regex='|'.join(search_list))
```

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Apple, Airplanne, Banana, Ball, Bat]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 0):

## Method 1 using str.contains

You can use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) in combination with [`DataFrame.columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html):

```
filtered_df = df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(search_list))]]

print(filtered_df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Apple, Airplanne, Banana, Ball, Bat]
Index: []
```

**Note** I just made an empty dataframe as example

`str.contains` returns a boolean array:

```
df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(search_list))

array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,
       False])
```

## Method 2 using Regex with DataFrame.filter

We can also use `DataFrame.filter` but then you need quite a complex `regex` statement found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33406313/how-to-match-any-string-from-a-list-of-strings-in-regular-expressions-in-python) answer

```
filtered_df = df.filter(regex=r"(?=("+'|'.join(search_list)+r"))")

print(filtered_df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Apple, Airplanne, Banana, Ball, Bat]
Index: []
```