# Regular expressions - counting how many times a word appears in a text

Tags: python, regex

What I am trying to set up is a function that given a certain text will print out the number of times the words `['color', 'Colour', 'Color','Colour']`appear. So that I get the following result:

```
assert colorcount("Color Purple") == 1

assert colorcount("Your colour is better than my colour") == 2

assert colorcount("color Color colour Colour") == 4
```

---

What I have is

```
import re

def colorcount(text):

all_matches = re.findall('color', 'Colour', 'Color'. 'Colour', text)

return len(all_matches)

print(colorcount(text)
```

It doesn't work so how can I write the code to make it work as I want it to?

Comment: Is it preferable to write all_matches = re.findall('[cC]olou*r', text)

Comment: `re.findall('[c|C]olour', text)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match any string from a list of strings in regular expressions in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33406313/how-to-match-any-string-from-a-list-of-strings-in-regular-expressions-in-python)

Comment: But then doesn't that exclude color and Color ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to use regular expressions, you could go for something like this:

```
import re

def colorcount(text):
  r = re.compile(r'\bcolour\b | \bcolor\b', flags = re.I | re.X)
  count = len(r.findall(text))
  print(count)
  return count

# These asserts work as expected without raising an AssertionError.
assert colorcount("Color Purple") == 1
assert colorcount("Your colour is better than my colour") == 2
assert colorcount("color Color colour Colour") == 4
```

Which outputs:

```
1
2
4
```

Comment: Is there an alternative way that doesn't require me to have the sentences in text? I mean to say that text = whatever is the text inside colorcount?

Comment: Ok! Is there a way to do it without specifying what the texts are? Now you are saying what sentences to search in but is there a way to make the code search in whatever text is in the asserts?

Comment: @solid.py Is there a way to not specify what the texts are? I.e. not have the texts = ['color...] but make it so texts = whatever the text within the asserts are?

Comment: @solid.py Before I go on thank you very much for your help so far I'll reward you best answer when done :) I am a beginner at this but what I mean is there a way (maybe there isn't I'm not sure) that I do not at all require to include or write what the text inside of colorcount() is? To have code that when asserted with whatever text someone tests it with returns the number of colors there is? Tell me if what I am asking makes sense..

Comment: @P.ython the return sends the value to the assert, and the print returns the number of colours to you as a user.

Comment: Oh yes! Exactly what I mean, sorry I didn't realize! Thank you very much, will you be available in future when I have python issues? :)

Comment: @P.ython Sure ask away, I always watch for new python questions, when I am available, I will try my best to answer. Also sidenote: (Since return is the last statement reached by the function, print before return.)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert text to specific case (i.e. all lower) and then use string's `count()` to loop each occurrence of a keyword:

```
def colorcount(text):
    KEY_WORDS = [ 'color', 'colour' ]
    counter = 0
    sanitexed_text = text.lower()
    for kw in KEY_WORDS:
        counter += sanitexed_text.count(kw.lower())
    return counter

text = 'color ds das Colour dsafasft e re Color'

# 3
print(colorcount(text))

# All following asserts pass
assert colorcount("Color Purple") == 1
assert colorcount("Your colour is better than my colour") == 2
assert colorcount("color Color colour Colour") == 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def colorcount(text):
    return len(re.findall('[c|C]olou{0,1}r', text))

assert colorcount("Color Purple") == 1
assert colorcount("Your colour is better than my colour") == 2
assert colorcount("color Color colour Colour") == 4
```

Comment: Can it be done in a way so that I only say e.g. print the length of findall for the text inside colorcount, whatever it may be i.e. that in the code I don't have "coloe purple" or anything but that when I run the assert it only counts the colors in whatever the text in assert says?

Comment: i don't understand what you are asking about

Comment: I don't want it to say 

print(colorcount("Color Purple")) #1

print(colorcount("Your colour is better than my colour")) #2

print(colorcount("color Color colour Colour"))

I want to have it count in whatever text is in the assert

Comment: Oh ok! So now how can I make it print out what the length is without specifying what the text is so that whatever the text within assert is it will return the number e.g. 
assert colorcount("color Color colour Colour") == 4

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex with flags `re.I` (case insensitivity) and `re.findll` and then return the length of the returned list:

```
\bcolou?r\b
```

```
import re

def colorcount(text):
  return len(re.findall(r'\bcolou?r\b', text, flags=re.I))

print(colorcount('color Color colour Colour'))
```

Prints:

4

Comment: This is almost what I want, only I don't want it to count only the text 'color Color colour Colour' but any text that is given within colorcount. How can I do that?

Comment: I believe you just "moved the goalposts." That is not at all what your question stated and your new comment to this answer is not at all clear what you are looking for. You need to update your question with precise specifics. Post a new comment to me when you have updated your question.