# How to use any string from list as a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, voice-recognition

I would like to know how i could have a variable `A` to be any random string from `ListA` and `B` to be any random string from `ListB`?

I would like to use this in a voice assistant and `Voice` would be the string containing the recognized sentence.
It should make a google search of anything I say between string `A` and string `B`.

```
import re
import webbrowser

ListA = ["search", "research"]
ListB = ["on google", "using google"]

A = # any string from ListA
B = # any string from ListB

Search = re.search(A + '(.+?)' B + , Voice).group(1)
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + Search
webbrowser.get().open(url)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match any string from a list of strings in regular expressions in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33406313/how-to-match-any-string-from-a-list-of-strings-in-regular-expressions-in-python)

Comment: BTW, welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: I tried it @wjandrea, but it would onl work for one list, not with both simultaniously.

Comment: What I was thinking about is to split the Voice string into a list and return the string that match.
For example : Voice = "Hi, could you research this and that on google"
                       Voice_List = Voice.split()
                       List_A = ["research", "search"]
                       List_B = ["on google", "using google", "with google"]
                       Word_A = any_word in Voice_List AND in List_A
                       Word_B = any_word in Voice_List AND in List_B

                       webbrowser.get().set(anything between Word_A and Word_B)

Comment: Looking at that question again, the top answer was really confusing, so I edited it. Please check it again. If it still doesn't work, then for debugging help, we'll need to know what you tried exactly, so make a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading what exists in the [`random` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html).

This is one of the things it offers:

```
list_a = ["search", "research"]
a = random.choice(list_a)
```

Comment: This is what I thought too at first, but OP's use of  "random" seems to be a misnomer. If you read the question more closely, OP has a string `Voice` that they're trying to match against any combination of the phrases in the lists. Doing that with random choices wouldn't make any sense. I proposed a duplicate.

Comment: Actually this is helpfull towards what I was looking for! Thank you verry much!!!

Comment: But, immagine I say "research blablabla on google" but a was chosen to be search, than my code wouldn't recognize me as searching for something on the browser.