# how to Return a string that is pressent in two different lists?

Tags: python, string, list, split, python-webbrowser

Hi I'm new to python and I'm making a voice assistant.

The Voice string contains what I've said using speech.recognition.

I was thinking to split the Voice string into a list and return the string that match.

For example : Voice = "Hi, could you research **this and that** on google"

I asked it in a different way, but I think I didn't ask properly what I was looking for.
[How to use any string from list as a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65535646/how-to-use-any-string-from-list-as-a-variable)

```
Voice_List = Voice.split()

List_A = ["research", "search"]
List_B = ["on google", "using google", "with google"]

Word_A = any_word in Voice_List AND in List_A
Word_B = any_word in Voice_List AND in List_B

webbrowser.get().set(anything between Word_A and Word_B)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you can specify your voice list as a set as well as your list_a or list_b as another set. Then you can apply the intersection function directly.

```py
Voice_Set = set(Voice.split())

Set_A = set(["research", "search"])
Set_B = set(["on google", "using google", "with google"])

Word_A = Voice_Set.intersection(Set_A)
Word_B = Voice_Set.intersection(Set_B)
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I create a string/set containing what's between Word_A and Word_B?

Comment: You can apply the sample idea:
`final_set = Word_A.intersection(Word_B)`