# How to match two character classes in 1 regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

the list of strings I want to iterate through look like this
**{"text":Foo bar\01d"},**
out of which I want to extract **Foo bar**.
I tried

```
f = open ("file.json", "r")
for line in f.readlines():
  #for left side
  leftSide = re.compile(r'([^{"text":].*)')
  mo = leftSide.findall(line)

for line in f.readlines():
  #rightside
  rightSide = re.compile(r'.*[\\01d"}$]')
  mo2 = rightSide.findall(line)
```

I have also unsuccessfully tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33406313/how-to-match-any-string-from-a-list-of-strings-in-regular-expressions-in-python).
Is it possible to match both in one regex or extract the data in one piece?

Comment: Do not use regular expressions for json parsing. There's [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module, use it. `json.load(f)`

Comment: okay, but i also have the txt version of the files, will use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using:

```
import re

f = open ("file.json", "r")

for l in f.readlines():

    print (re.split(r'"text":|\x01d',l)[1])
```

With:

```
l = '{"text":Foo bar\01d"},'

print (re.split(r'"text":|\x01d',l)[1])
```

Output:

```
Foo bar
```

Here we use a regex split, which uses left and right side delimiters, and take index 1.

Comment: You should not parse json using regular expressions.

Comment: I know. But see OP's comment in his original post.

Comment: I don't understand meaning of those comment, *txt* version of *json* file is a text file with json formatted data, imho.

Comment: Same here. Sometimes peoples need to make their own understanding ;).