# Is there a way to create a regex by comparing one or more strings

Tags: python, regex

I want to be able to programmatically create a regular expression that would match to any one of a list of strings passed to it, to be used to match individual strings.

*EDIT*
I'm hoping somebody out there knows of an existing Python module that will do this, or can be adapted to do so. If you don't understand what I'm trying to do, please move on to another question. DO NOT merge this with another completely unrelated question or close it because you don't know what the word topic means!

It will probably look, something along the lines of:

```
sample_list = ['Daily updates September - Brighton branch', 
               'Daily updates October - Brighton branch', 
               'Daily updates September - Leeds branch']

def create_regex(list_of_strings: list):
   pattern = do_some_magic()
   return re.compile(pattern)

regex_heading = create_regex(sample_list)
```

I then need to use the regex to match a subsequent string.

```
result = re.match(regex_heading, 'Daily updates November - Weston branch')
```

result should be True

```
result = re.match(regex_heading, 'Weekly updates November - Weston branch')
```

result should be False

To be clear, I can create the regex for this case quite easily, but I want to be able to do it for any random list of strings.

Comment: What exactly is the rule for this regex?  Trivially I would write the function `def magic_match(a): return lambda x : a.split("-")[-1] in x` for this case.  Is that all you mean?  Or is there some greater rule for what counts as a valid and an invalid string?

Comment: This question is off-topic, not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33406313/how-to-match-any-string-from-a-list-of-strings-in-regular-expressions-in-python).

Comment: I will vote to close because the question is off-topic, specifically the scope is open-ended with an unrealistic objective. It's akin to writing a function that would take as input scientific observations and produce an equation that embodies a physical law. (Since beginning this comment the question was closed.)

Comment: The topics for this question are Python and regex. 
What I'm asking is if anyone knows of a way to do something using regex, in Python.

Comment: So, in a way, you wish to find the "smallest common denominator" in regex form of an arbitrary list of strings? That's actually pretty cool and on-topic.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why is it off-topic? It's absolutely about programming, it's absolutely answerable, code was provided with expected result and sample data. I agree it's more off-topic than a duplicate of the other question however, but there are clear ways of doing the desired behaviour.

Comment: If it were on-topic, we would see your attempt at `do_some_magic` implementation with explanation what did not work. Otherwise, it is not a question, but a code request. Besides, "*I'm hoping somebody out there knows of an existing Python module*" proves you are looking for some 3rd party library, and it is [definitely off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).