# Regular Expressions: Search in array list

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, list, boto3

I want to filter strings in a list based on a regular expression. I tried defining as variable ${TagValue} but it gives null value or an empty list:

Bascially i want to list down those instances that have Environment tag is equal to the "Tag Value":

Here's my code:

```
TagValue = ['DEV', 'DEVDR', 'QA','TEST', 'SND', 'STG', 'sit', 'sandbox', 'Development', 'NonProd', 'NON-PROD']
instance_list = []
Instances = ec2_resource.instances.all()
for each in Instances:
    instance_list.append(each.id) # count total # of instances including all env tags 
        
for i in instance_list:
    ins_res = ec2_resource.Instance(i)
    ins_tag = ins_res.tags
    ins_state = ins_res.state
    if ins_state['Name']=='running':
        for item in ins_tag:
            if item['Key'] == 'Environment':
                val = item['Value']
                pattern = re.compile(r'\b${tag_value}\w*', re.IGNORECASE)
                print(re.findall(pattern,val))
```

Output is:

```
[]
[]
[]
.....
```

Comment: A couple things about this I don't understand. You define TagValue, but then don't use it anywhere. The {tag_value} in r'\b${tag_value}\w*' isn't getting replaced with something meaningful right? It's just the plain string "{tag_value}".

Comment: `$` in the regexp matches the end of the string. It doesn't make sense to have `{tag_value}` after that.

Comment: Are you confusing Python f-strings with JavaScript template literals? In Python you don't put `$` before `{expression}`.

Comment: Are you trying to find any of the words in `TagValue`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33406313/how-to-match-any-string-from-a-list-of-strings-in-regular-expressions-in-python

Comment: Note that you can supply filters on the [describe_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2/client/describe_instances.html) call though it doesn't support regular expressions.